# Drupal 7 not showing frontpage?

Tags: drupal-7

I am a new Drupal CMS application developer, I have create redirect function using redirect, trigger module and integrate succefully. The page redirect direct to login working fine. The trigger action create after user logged in redirect to frontpage. Trigged was showing user page, but the not showing frontpage.

The below configuration in my Drupal site:

redirect module - redirect from frontpage to user login page

system - action - choose action - redirect to - frontpage[site:url] assign available token

goto structure trigger - user tab - after user logged in - assign to action funtion

Answer (score 0):

redirect module can be replaced with [R4032Login (Redirect 403 users to login page eg.)](https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login)

*Don't rebuild the wheel, use it :D*